# React Hooks setUser & setUserId not updating state despite correct data output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a functional component using React hooks. There are quite a few functions that will be running in this component, but one in particular is outputting information correctly but not updating the state as it should.

```
function StatusDropdown() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('')
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
      getUser()
    }, [])

    function getUser() {
        return fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(jsonUser => {
                setUser(jsonUser.display_name)
                setUserId(jsonUser.id)
                console.log(`userInfo: ${jsonUser.id} & ${jsonUser.display_name}`)
                //This console log returns proper information: userInfo: 7 & Firstname
            })
    }
}
```

I stripped away the unnecessary code, but whenever the user and userId state get used further in my component, the user returns undefined. I use the user state to pass it as an API call query, but because it ends up returning undefined, the API does not properly filter data about a specific user.

I'm just trying to understand if I'm missing something specifically. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Below is the subsequent code that relies on the user information above:

```
    function getAuxLog(userId) {
        return fetch(`${url}?user=${userId}`, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(auxlogJson => {
                setUserAuxLog(auxlogJson)
                setLatestAuxLog(auxlogJson.data[auxlogJson.data.length - 1])
                setAuxLogLoaded(true)
            })
    }
```

The userId is passed to the API url in order to retrieve a log of activity statuses for a specific user. However, with the userId state not being updated, it can not properly retrieve this logged data.

Comment: `user` is not a function, so it cannot return anything. the code here looks ok, please edit your question to include the code where your experience THE PROBLEM

Comment: maybe it's about the asynchronous nature of setState functions - the value of the constant `user` will be always `''` during the first render. it will be `Firstname` only in the next render after calling `setUser('Firstname')`, and any functions executed during the 1st render won't be able to access any new values, only the initial value `''`

Comment: Everything in this code looks fine, so the culprit is likely one of the 'quite a few functions' or 'unnecessary' pieces of code you stripped away.